# How the object 'window' bind addEventListener()?

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript and I know there is a window object.

I log this object, find lots of functions but I can't find the function `addEventListener`, which I have used it lots of times.

I always use this function like:

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert(123)
});
```

I want know when `addEventListener()` bind this object window?

Comment: yes。I use consol.log(window),but i can't find this function: addEventListener.

Comment: open browser dev tools (F12 in Chrome), go to console tab, write: window.addE ... and waits for the autocomplete... addEventListener is on window object

Comment: `addEventListener` is a property of `EventTarget.prototype` - window inherits (indirectly) from `EventTarget` - `console.log(window)`, then follow the prototype chain in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Window` inherits the `addEventListener` method from `EventTarget` on its `prototype`. In other words, it doesn't define it itself, so it's not listed on its own methods, and you have to follow the prototype chain.

[image: window prototype]

Comment: `EventTarget` isn't *on* `window`'s prototype, an instance of `EventTarget` *is* one of its prototypes, at least on some browsers (specifically, in the above and on Chrome, the third down: `window`'s prototype is a `Window` object, whose prototype is a `WindowProperties` object, whose prototype is an `EventTarget` object). Still, a picture is worth 1024 words... :-)

Comment: Note: `Window ... WindowProperties ... EventTarget` same chain in Firefox

Comment: Sidenote: I like the `WindowProperties Prototype` → *No Properties*… -_____-